# Fragment Call Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a strange issue in Android Fragments. I have 4 fragments in my activity with action bar. Initially I am in 4th Fragment. I have a search bar in menu which is specific to 4th fragment alone. I go to the 4th fragment and I type something to search and click enter. When I click enter it moves to the first fragment.

I don't know why its coming to the first fragment. please help me.

Comment: No code == No answer == No Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. I am using search interface in my 4th fragment to implement search functionality. I am supposed to handle the "ACTION_SEARCH" Intent from a seperate activity other than my fragment's parent activity. But I tried to handle the "ACTION_SEARCH" intent from my fragment's parent activity. That made this issue to come.

Thanks to @user2247689 & @Android Venkatesh for trying to help me out immediately.